# Hear for event outside Marionette ItemView

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following html -

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="one">
            <-- Marionette ItemView V1 rendered here -->
        </diV>

        <div id="two">
            <-- Mariontette ItemView V2 rendered here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I listen to mouseup event in `#two` within `#one` like so:

```
var V1= Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#template_for_div#one",

    event: {
        "mouseup #two": "do_something",
        // Other events
    },

    // Other stuff
});
```

Comment: could your replicate this on plunker/fiddle?

Comment: fiddle wont allow me to add backbone and marionette as dependenceis :(

Comment: try using codepen.io

Comment: @VijaySingh if you want two views to communicate, why not have a parent view that facilitates it..?

Comment: @TJ, could you please explain a bit more, are you talking about a CompositeView?

Comment: This violates MVC, which is the purpose of Marionette.  What object is creating the View objects?  It should be a controller-like object (component, controller, etc.)  That object can listen to view1 for its event, then call a method on view2 when that event fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to solve this problem is to create a `dispatcher` object that both objects have reference to. Trigger and listen to events on this object. (To clarify, this object is now a view, rather it is a backbone events object whose only job is to dispatch events.)

The Backbone docs say this under the Backbone.Events section: http://backbonejs.org/#Events
*"For example, to make a handy event dispatcher that can coordinate events among different areas of your application: var dispatcher = _.clone(Backbone.Events)"*